How to filter logs in fluent bit?
I'm trying to filter logs to make it cleaner and more readable before forwarding it to ElasticSearch
This is one of the example raw logs i'm receiving:
Jun 25 13:27:34 host3 fluent-bit[745468]: [0] cpu_usage: [[1719322045.744281337, {}], {"cpu_p"=>3.250000, "user_p"=>2.750000, "system_p"=>1.60000, "cpu0.p_cpu"=>3.000000, "cpu0.p_user"=>2.000000, "cpu0.p_system"=>1.000000, "cpu1.p_cpu"=>5.600000, "cpu1.p_user"=>4.8000000, "cpu1.p_system"=>0.800000, "cpu2.p_cpu"=>3.000000, "cpu2.p_user"=>2.000000, "cpu2.p_system"=>1.000000, "cpu3.p_cpu"=>5.600000, "cpu3.p_user"=>4.8000000, "cpu3.p_system"=>0.800000}]
fluent-bit.conf:
[SERVICE]
    Daemon Off
    Flush 1
    Log_Level info
    Parsers_File parsers.conf
    HTTP_Server On
    HTTP_Listen 0.0.0.0
    HTTP_Port 2020
    Health_Check On

[INPUT]
    Name cpu
    Tag cpu_usage
    Interval_Sec 5

[FILTER]
    Name parser
    Match cpu_usage*
    Key_Name filtered_cpu
    Parser custom-log-filter

[OUTPUT]
    Name Stdout
    Match *

I'm using Regex to filter out the strings that I want to remove. In my parsers.conf this is my configuration
parsers.conf:
[PARSER]
     Name   custom-log-filter
     Format regex
     Regex  ^\w{3} \d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2} .*?: \[0\] |\[.+\], |]$

Using https://regexr.com/ I was able to select the strings that I want to remove. How do I "reverse" the selection such that I return everything else other than the one selected. Please let me know if there's a better way of doing this. Thanks in advance
Expected Output:
host3 cpu_usage: {"cpu_p"=>3.250000, "user_p"=>2.750000, "system_p"=>1.60000, "cpu0.p_cpu"=>3.000000, "cpu0.p_user"=>2.000000, "cpu0.p_system"=>1.000000, "cpu1.p_cpu"=>5.600000, "cpu1.p_user"=>4.8000000, "cpu1.p_system"=>0.800000, "cpu2.p_cpu"=>3.000000, "cpu2.p_user"=>2.000000, "cpu2.p_system"=>1.000000, "cpu3.p_cpu"=>5.600000, "cpu3.p_user"=>4.8000000, "cpu3.p_system"=>0.800000}
Received Output:
So far I still can't receive the filtered output.
